# How to set up file-io-dispatcher at akka http?

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream, akka-http

When I was trying to start `akka` I had this error with `ConfigFactory.load()`:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.typesafe.config.ConfigException$UnresolvedSubstitution: reference.conf @ jar:file:/home/faoxis/.ivy2/cache/com.typesafe.akka/akka-http_2.12/jars/akka-http_2.12-10.1.5.jar!/reference.conf: 51: Could not resolve substitution to a value: ${akka.stream.blocking-io-dispatcher}
```

In source code I found this:

```
# Fully qualified config path which holds the dispatcher configuration
  # to be used by FlowMaterialiser when creating Actors for IO operations.
  file-io-dispatcher = ${akka.stream.blocking-io-dispatcher}
```

I have a question with it. Can I use some default setting without using environment variable `akka.stream.blocking-io-dispatcher`? Maybe I can set up that by `application.conf`?

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you can do with `application.conf` and `Environment Variables` is override properties that are defined in `reference.conf`.

So you can configure `akka.stream.blocking-io-dispatcher` in any of them.

Strange is that usually there is a default value set. I use `akka-http` with Play and I never had to set any configuration.

See here the `akka-streams` Configuration: [stream-configuration](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/general/stream/stream-configuration.html)